# Aura component show the same for every customer

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura

I have an aura component that shows data that are called by an API. If I open the component on a customer (B) account and if I had the same component opened on another customer account (A) the data related to customer account B will show on the component of the account from customer A. Is there any way to refresh the component every time I change the tab inside salesforce?

Thanks

Comment: Is this a console based application?

Answer (score 0):

You first need to add the appropriate interface:

```
<aura:component implements="force:hasRecordid">
```

And then add a handler to listen for changes:

```
<aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.recordId}" action="{!c.loadRecord}" />
```

Or, you can also use `<force:recordData>`:

```
<force:recordData recordId="{!v.recordId}" layout="FULL" recordUpdated="{!c.updateComponentState}" />
```